# I cannot find a text string referened in the the .rdata

Tags: ida

I'm trying to disassemble an application (built from a Chinese company in English).

I find the text string I want:

```
.data:0041048C aEraseError     db 'Erase error !',0Ah,0 ; DATA XREF:
.rdata:0040C624o
.data:0041048C                                         ; .rdata:0040CF28o ...
```

But, I cannot locate it in the code anywhere. It's strange some text strings are found but others are not.

FYI: The application also loads a custom `.dll` file. The text is located in the main exe file's `.rdata` segment, but I just cannot see it in the code. I've tried with other disassemblers but I am using IDA.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your string seems to have an xref (cross reference, see below) from `0040C624`. This string might just be an entry in an array of error strings, with the array itself beginning just a little before `0040C624`. Your original source code may have looked like this:

```
char *unused="unused string";
char *errors[] = {
    "error 0",
    "some other error",
    "yet another error",
    "Erase error!",
    "....",
};

void print_error_message(int index) {
    puts(errors[index]);
}

int handle_erase_error() {
    print_error_message(3);
}
```

If you compile this (i used gnu C on linux, `gcc -m32 xref.c`) and load the object code into IDA, it becomes (irrelevant parts omitted):

```
.text:08000000 print_error_message proc near           ; CODE XREF: handle_erase_error+Dp
.text:08000000                 push    ebp
.text:08000001                 mov     ebp, esp
.text:08000003                 sub     esp, 18h
.text:08000006                 mov     eax, [ebp+8]
.text:08000009                 mov     eax, errors[eax*4]
.text:08000010                 mov     [esp], eax      ; s
.text:08000013                 call    puts
.text:08000018                 leave
.text:08000019                 retn
.text:08000019 print_error_message endp


.data:08000030 unused          dd offset aUnusedString ; "unused string"
.data:08000034 errors          dd offset aError0       ; DATA XREF: print_error_message+9r
.data:08000034                                         ; "error 0"
.data:08000038                 dd offset aSomeOtherError ; "some other error"
.data:0800003C                 dd offset aYetAnotherErro ; "yet another error"
.data:08000040                 dd offset aEraseError   ; "Erase error!"
.data:08000044                 dd offset a____         ; "...."

.rodata:08000049 aUnusedString   db 'unused string',0    ; DATA XREF: .data:unusedo
.rodata:08000057 aError0         db 'error 0',0          ; DATA XREF: .data:errorso
.rodata:0800005F aSomeOtherError db 'some other error',0 ; DATA XREF: .data:08000038o
.rodata:08000070 aYetAnotherErro db 'yet another error',0 ; DATA XREF: .data:0800003Co
.rodata:08000082 aEraseError     db 'Erase error!',0     ; DATA XREF: .data:08000040o
.rodata:0800008F a____           db '....',0             ; DATA XREF: .data:08000044o
```

You see that each string has a pointer entry in the `data` section, and the ascii data in the `rodata` (read only data) section. And each of the ascii strings has an xref (cross reference) to the pointer that points to it - this is not a part of the binary; ida detects where each string is referenced, and generates the "backreferences", or xrefs.

The important thing is: you can use this to find the string table (errors, at `0x08000034`) if you have only the ascii bytes. And you can find where the string table itself is used by looking at its xref - from the print_error_message function. In contrast, the unused string does *not* have an xref, because it isn't used anywhere.

Ida will allow you to double-click on the xref to move to where it 'comes from' to navigate easily.

I'd check if you have an array of strings that starts a bit before the xref to your string, where it gets used, and possibly where the using function gets called.

---

Another possibility is something that i saw a few days ago in an ARM android shared library. The library had some strings holding function names, directly after each other, like this (translated to x86 syntax)

```
errmsg    db 'Error in %s, file %s, line %d\n', 0
strtab    db 'opencachefile', 0
          db 'closecachefile', 0
          db 'getcacheentry', 0
          db 'putcacheentry', 0
          db 'delcacheentry', 0
```

The function that got something from cache used the third of these strings to log a possible error. The code looked like this (again, translated from arm to x86):

```
...
mov    eax, offset strtab
add    eax, 29           ;<-- difference in bytes between 'open' and 'get'
push   eax
mov    eax, offset errmsg
push   eax
call   android_log_print
```

The other functions had similar constructs, so `strtab` was referenced 5 times (one in each function), and the byte difference adjusted in each of them. I sincerely don't know why a compiler would do this, but just *maybe* something similar is going on in your code.

Comment: Thank you! This is a very good answer. Please could you show me what maybe an array of strings might look like in Assembly. Also, could you go into more details when you state: Your string seems to have an xref from 0040C624. what is an xref

0040C624